# Kernel Error in anaconda Jupyter Notebook: ImportError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I caught up with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 337, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 286, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 466, in write_connection_file
    self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 136, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\Abhilash H.P\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

How to troubleshoot this error?

I tried almost all possible solutions available on Stack Overflow, Youtube, and even i removed anaconda and Python and its dependencies completely and reinstalled the same. but still its not working.

Comment: try `conda install pywin32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to "pywin", try this if you already have that package :

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==225
```

Or this

```
pip install pywin32==225
```

Comment: Thank you so much...for your help its working now...

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved by resetting the environment variables...

If anyone caught up with same error just check the path of anaconda installation directory and check environment variables whether they are also matching the same...

Step 1: Search for Environment Variable in the windows search bar

Step 2: Under System properties dialog box select Environment Variables

Step 3: Check the Anaconda Installation Directory Path in your system (User/System)

Step 4: If it is in User,  Select Path under User Variables otherwise select Path under System Variables and Click on Edit

Step 5: Select New from Edit Environment Variables dialog box

Step 6: Paste the Anaconda Installation Directory Path.

Step 7: Done

Step 8: If it doesn't work better you delete all the Path Variables related to Python and Anaconda and Uninstall anaconda and its all dependencies, delete all the files related to Anaconda and Python...and reinstall anaconda...It works...

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps:

1. To craete new virtual environment in Anaconda type the following Command
   ***Step 1: conda create -n myenv python=Version (python=3.8)***
2. First activate the created environment
   ***Step 2: conda activate myenv***
3. First, activate your virtual environment and run this code.
   ***Step 3:pip install --user ipykernel***
4. We need to manually add the kernel if we want to have the virtual environment in the Jupyter Notebook. That is why we need to add it by running this code.
   ***Step 4: python -m ipykernel install --user --name=myenv***

***With this, we have set up our virtual environment kernel and ready to be used in the Jupyter Notebook.***

***In my case error is because  of, DLL load failed while importing win32api, this Import Error.***

It is resolved by the command by @Alama1:
***pip install pywin32==225***